# Differences between calculating correlation and feature selection for feature variables?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-mining

What would be the difference between using correlation and using feature selection to select important/highly correlated variables? When researching feature selection, I see that it uses statistical tests including pearson correlation.

Part of a college project, our group wants to identify important variables when doing data mining. A partner did correlation analysis using R Studio and I did recursive feature elimination using Sci-kit Learn.

When doing this, one variable was in common between the top 3 highest correlated variables and the top three ranked variables via recursive feature elimination.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am rather new to this!

Answer (score 0):

You can suspect that the most correlated features are redundant. However you cannot say how does the feature influence the performance exactly. Correlation is informative, but the different feature selection techniques can be completely distinct, so it is worth to use them also. Then you can merge the results, for example verify if the correlated feature was redundant.

You can find interesting information here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

As you can see, tree-based feature selection can be biased by the tree model, but it gives the answer of how much given feature influenced the decisions. This may be completely different indicator than the correlation.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. We wanted to have two different methods to identify the important variables so we don't rely on one alone. I see that RFE supports a wrapper method with cross validation RFECV. Maybe a better question would be how does the regular RFE with Sklearn compute the rankings? I was able to get the code to work and did find the rankings, I just want to get a better understanding of how/on what basis the rankings given.